# Pandas data table manipulation

Tags: python, sql, pandas, bioinformatics

The first 15 lines of my table looks like this:

```
ch  S-MART  utr5    313 516 .   +   .   blabla
ch  GenBank gene    517 1878    .   +   1   ID=SAOUHSC_00001;Name=SAOUHSC_00001
ch  GenBank mRNA    517 1878    .   +   1   ID=SAOUHSC_00001.t01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00001
ch  GenBank CDS 517 1878    .   +   1   ID=SAOUHSC_00001.p01;Name=SAOUHSC_00001;product=chromosomal 
ch  GenBank exon    517 1878    .   +   1   Parent=SAOUHSC_00001.t01
ch  S-MART  gene    517 1878    .   +   .   blabla
ch  S-MART  operon  1879    2155    .   +   .   blabla
ch  GenBank gene    2156    3289    .   +   1   ID=SAOUHSC_00002;Name=SAOUHSC_00002
ch  GenBank mRNA    2156    3289    .   +   1   ID=SAOUHSC_00002.t01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00002
ch  GenBank CDS 2156    3289    .   +   1   ID=SAOUHSC_00002.p01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00002.t01;Name=SAOUHSC_00002;product=DNA polymerase 
ch  S-MART  utr3    3290    3331    .   +   .   blabla
ch  S-MART  utr5    3649    3669    .   +   .   blabla
ch  GenBank gene    3670    3915    .   +   1   ID=SAOUHSC_00003;Name=SAOUHSC_00003
ch  GenBank CDS 3670    3915    .   +   1   ID=SAOUHSC_00003.p01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00003.t01;Name=SAOUHSC_00003;product=conserved  
ch  S-MART  gene    3670    5024    .   +   .   blabla
```

This type of standard file is called GFF, for reference its definition can be found here http://www.sequenceontology.org/gff3.shtml.

The fourth and fifth column of this table indicates a start and stop coordinate. I am trying to shrink this table based on these start and stop coordinates.

I use the following code to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
staphInputGff = pd.read_table("myTable", sep='\t',names=["seqid", "source", "type","start","end","score","strand","phase","attributes"])
start = staphInputGff.start
end = staphInputGff.end

def consolidate(start, end):
    _start = start[:]                # Make a copy since we're modifying the list
    result = []
    for i in range(len(_start)-1):   # Iterate until the second-to-last pair
        if _start[i+1] <= end[i]+1 and (start[i+1] != _start[i] or end[i+1] != end[i]):  # If two pairs are contiguous,
            _start[i+1] = _start[i]  # replace the start value with the previous one
        elif start[i+1] != _start[i] or end[i+1] != end[i]:                                  # Otherwise
            result.append((_start[i], end[i])) # add the current pair to the result
    result.append((_start[i+1], end[i+1]))     # the ultimate pair
    return result
consolidate(start,end)
```

It gives the following result:

```
(313, 3331), (3649, 5024)
```

The continuous start and end coordinates that are side by side are merged.

For example the first line has start and end coordinates (313,516). Since the next line had start and end coordinates (517,1878), this is merged to (313,1878). This continues a few lines later where the coordinates are (1879,2155) and again at (3290,3331). The end result is (313,3331)

I need to print the table back for a specific key -- only CDS is enough(i do not want information from other rows).

For only the CDS named entries, the final result should look like this,

```
ch  GenBank CDS 313 3331    .   +   .   ID=SAOUHSC_00001.p01;Name=SAOUHSC_00001;product=chromosomal
ch  GenBank CDS 3649 5024   .   +   .   ID=SAOUHSC_00003.p01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00003.t01;Name=SAOUHSC_00003;product=conserved
```

To do this, I think I need to use merge, join, concatenate or boolean indexing or grouping in Pandas.

What is the right approach?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how you merge the coordinates? Is it based on the source name or the type? Where is the (1879,3289) pair coming from? How do you choose which entry will get the (313, 3331) or the (3649, 5024)? What version of pandas and python are you using? Also, are you using tabs or spaces in your myTable file?

Comment: It is based on start and end. Please look at the 4th and 5th column. I merge them if  they are continuing

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to see it. How do you choose the source and type name for your output? Is it based on the range that the respective entries originally lie in? For instance the next entry CDS (ID=SAOUHSC_0003.p01) is originally (3670 3915) so we would assign it (3649 5024)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need to print all other columns with the new start and end. These other columns should be taken from the row with CDS as  its 3rd column

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample file please?

Comment: @Korem: could you please copy the first 15 lines which I have pasted above and save it as "myTable"

Comment: It is a very big file. I cannot post it

Comment: To get the example as posted to work (copy and paste), you can use: pd.read_table("myTable", sep=r"\s*",names=["seqid", "source", "type","start","end","score","strand","phase","attributes"]). You must remove the space from "product=DNA polymerase" though.

Comment: Also, @user3683555, what have you tried? Did you get stuck using merge and join? Any errors?

Comment: Yes,I got stuck. The documentation is too big that it will take atleast 2 days to understand all the functions in pandas documentation. But, I am doing that now. Infact this is part of a bigger problem. I created this GFF file by extracting data from different databases. I was using R prior to this . But, now I am learning pandas.

Comment: Are the continuous sections guaranteed to be sequential?  For example, is it ever possible to have rows that would include (1, 516) ... (1879,2155) ... (517, 1878) in that order?  In other words, do you only need to look one row ahead, or do you need to scan the entire table?

Comment: @iayork: Yes, it is guaranteed to be sequential.

Comment: I just sorted the entire table to be sequential

Comment: In some cases, you have multiple CDS within the same set of contiguous sequences. For example, the CDS (517, 1878) will end up merged with the CDS (2156, 3289). However, the information in the final column is different.  How do you want to handle the information in this case?

Comment: Yes, In that case, print only the first CDS information. For eg., between CDS (517, 1878) and CDS (2156, 3289), choose only the first one .i.e., CDS (517, 1878)

Comment: we need to write a apply function first and then use group by. This is my latest guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible, but very ugly, solution.  It's basically a series of hacks. Hopefully it will annoy some of the people who actually know what they're doing enough to post a nicer solution.

```
# start with the data in a data frame df

df
     a        b       c  Start   End  f  g  h                                                  i

    0   ch   S-MART    utr5    313   516  .  +  .                                             blabla
    1   ch  GenBank    gene    517  1878  .  +  1                ID=SAOUHSC_00001;Name=SAOUHSC_00001
    2   ch  GenBank    mRNA    517  1878  .  +  1          ID=SAOUHSC_00001.t01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00001
    3   ch  GenBank     CDS    517  1878  .  +  1  ID=SAOUHSC_00001.p01;Name=SAOUHSC_00001;produc...
    4   ch  GenBank    exon    517  1878  .  +  1                           Parent=SAOUHSC_00001.t01
    5   ch   S-MART    gene    517  1878  .  +  .                                             blabla
    6   ch   S-MART  operon   1879  2155  .  +  .                                             blabla
    7   ch  GenBank    gene   2156  3289  .  +  1                ID=SAOUHSC_00002;Name=SAOUHSC_00002
    8   ch  GenBank    mRNA   2156  3289  .  +  1          ID=SAOUHSC_00002.t01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00002
    9   ch  GenBank     CDS   2156  3289  .  +  1  ID=SAOUHSC_00002.p01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00002.t01;...
    10  ch   S-MART    utr3   3290  3331  .  +  .                                             blabla
    11  ch   S-MART    utr5   3649  3669  .  +  .                                             blabla
    12  ch  GenBank    gene   3670  3915  .  +  1                ID=SAOUHSC_00003;Name=SAOUHSC_00003
    13  ch  GenBank     CDS   3670  3915  .  +  1  ID=SAOUHSC_00003.p01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00003.t01;...
    14  ch   S-MART    gene   3670  5024  .  +  .                                             blabla


# If there are duplicate start/end values, discard those that repeat the CDS 
cdsSE = df[df['c']=='CDS'][['Start','End']].values
droprows = []
for idx in df.index:
    if (df.loc[idx][['Start','End']].values in cdsSE) and (df.loc[idx]['c'] != 'CDS'):
        droprows.append(idx)
df2 = df.drop(df.index[droprows])

# Walk through the new data frame. If the next row is contiguous,
# move up the start value and mark the row for deletion

droprows = []
for i in range(len(df2.index[:-1])): 
    if (df2.iloc[i]['End'] + 1) >= df2.iloc[i+1]['Start']: # to include lesser start values

        # If the present row is CDS, 
        #save its information by also moving it up a row
        if df2.loc[df2.index[i], 'c'] == 'CDS':
            df2.loc[df2.index[i+1], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']] = df2.loc[df2.index[i], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']]

        # Then replace the start values with the present row
        # and mark the row for deletion
        df2.loc[df2.index[i+1], 'Start'] = df2.loc[df2.index[i], 'Start']
        droprows.append(i)

# And make a new data frame by deleting the unwanted rows
df3 = df2.drop(df2.index[droprows])

df3
    a        b    c  Start   End  f  g  h                                                  i
10  ch  GenBank  CDS    313  3331  .  +  1  ID=SAOUHSC_00001.p01;Name=SAOUHSC_00001;produc...
13  ch  GenBank  CDS   3649  3915  .  +  1  ID=SAOUHSC_00003.p01;Parent=SAOUHSC_00003.t01;...
```

Comment: nice solution. I will wait till tomorrow to see if there is simpler way. otherwise, I will accept this one.

Comment: Nice to know that you are working in Bioinformatic too. Pandas  package is very useful than the biopython package. I tried to do this using Biopython. Unfortunately, you cannot iterate through different elements/records in biopython but you can parse them easily. R is good with respect to bioinformatics but I think pandas will soon catch up. I am going to practise more in Pandas.